# Не изменяются данные на сайте

Tags: wordpress

Хочу изменить номер на сайте (находится в самом конце), обычно это делается через «настроить», в отдельную строку вписываю, там все есть, а на сайте номер на новый не изменяется. Как исправить?

Страница, с которой нужна помощь: http://new.gelios-pnz.ru

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Надпись под лого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1242202/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be)

Comment: эм..как бы вопросы то и разные

Comment: если номер не изменяется может быть два варианта: 1. вы не там правите 2. у вас кеш

Comment: все исправила, нашла где этот номер сидел! спасибо